# Get visibility on number of rabbitmq messages in flight when autoAck=true

Tags: rabbitmq

I have a RabbitMQ setup where a (java) producer sends messages to a fanout exchange, which are handled by a consumer. It's no problem if messages get lost when the consumer dies, so for performance I set autoAck=true at the consumer side.

Now I'm investigating a situation in which the rate the consumer can handle messages, is lower than the rate at which they are sent.

After a while, a (huge) backlog of messages must queue up somewhere. Is there a way to get visibility on this backlog?

Using the rabbitmqmanagement interface does not work: the queue appears empty

```
Ready: 0
Unacknowledged: 0
Total: 0
```

I assume the queue is empty because the messages are (unlimitedly) prefetched by the rabbitmqclient used by the consumer. But limiting the prefetch by e.g.

```
channel.basicQos(10)
```

does not help either, probably because this only limits unacknowledged messages, and with autoAck=true, messages are ack'ed from the moment they are prefetched by the client.

Setting autoAck=false (and explicit ack'ing on delivery) is a solution (the Unacknowledged counter keeps on rising), but I was wondering whether this is the only way?

Preferably I'd like to limit the amount of cached messages at the client side irrespective of acknowledgements, such that the backlog eventually becomes visible through the rabbitmqmanagement interface.

Alternatively, is there a way to query the number of messages sitting somewhere in the client's prefetch queue waiting to be delivered?

Comment: basicQos doesn't work with autoAck=true, because basicQos depends on it.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using a combination of basicQos and autoAck=false.  This will make everything show up in the  queues both through the admin website and the REST APIs.  Having an unlimited number of messages sent to each consumer seems to defeat the point of a queue.

If your queues are time sensitive you can also add a TTL on the queues so that messages are automatically Nacked after (as an example) 60 minutes.